# Initializing objects of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This command:

```
rails g model Product name quantity:integer
```

generates a model `Product` with two fields: `name`, which is a string, and `quantity`, which is an integer.

1. Are the fields instance variables of `Product`?
2. If so, when and where and how are they initialized?
3. When  creating a `Product` instance in a controller:

eg:

```
    def new
      @product = Product.new
    end
```

where is the `initialize` method called?

Comment: The initialize method is called when you use `.new`, for example, `Product.new(name: "foo", quantity: 1)`

Comment: Thank you @maxpleaner, are the fields name and quantity the instance variables of Product class?

Comment: You can also define initialize method in your model so provide default values for you instance variables

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a little more precise...

When you do:

```
rails g model Product name quantity:integer
```

You are not adding a product table to your database. You are creating a `migration` and a `model` (and perhaps some tests, depending...). You'll see something like:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20171129070104_create_products.rb
  create    app/models/product.rb
```

When you do:

```
rake db:migrate
```

THEN you're adding a table to your database. You'll see something like:

```
== 20171129070623 CreateProducts: migrating ==============
-- create_table(:products)
   -> 0.0179s
== 20171129070623 CreateProducts: migrated (0.0180s) =====
```

Once migrated, your `products` table will have columns named `name` and `quantity`.

To your questions:

> Are the fields instance variables of Product?

Roughly, yes. An instance of `Product` will have attributes for `name` and `quantity`. So, if you do (in console):

```
p = Product.new
```

You will see:

```
> p = Product.new
 => #<Product id: nil, name: nil, quantity: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

> If so, when and where are they initialized?

Instance attributes are initialized when calling `new` on a model class. If you call `new` with no arguments, then the attributes are initialized to `nil`.

You can also call `new` with arguments, such as:

```
> Product.new(name: 'foo', quantity: 2)
 => #<Product id: nil, name: "foo", quantity: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Where are they initialized? Anywhere you want. There are varying ideas about practices that are "good" and practices that are "bad". But, that's a much longer discussion.

Personally, I *never* interact (e.g., initialize, save, update, delete) with my models in my `controllers` or `views`. I have a custom class called `managers` and that is the *only* place I interact with my models. But, I am very odd in this regard and you should consider my practice "anomalous".

> When a creating a Product instance in a controller, where is the initialize method called?

As pointed out elsewhere, it is called when `new` is called. There are some subtleties, and you might want to look into `ActiveRecord::Callbacks`.

Also, as pointed out elsewhere, you can override `initialize` for any number of reasons.

By the way, `new` and `initialize` are not unique to models. It is very common to use them in plain old ruby objects.

Answer (score 1):

When you do: 
rails g model Product name quantity:integer.

What you are really doing is adding a product table to your database and adding a product model to your models. (And some other things that aren't largely important.) You are not creating an instance. However if you were to go to add to you table that you've just creating that would be initializing; and that usually happens in the following places: in your console, in your seed file, in your tests, in the browser, and sometimes in other models and controllers.

Last note, when you initialize a new product you don't to make your own new method. Ruby already has taken care of that for you. Just initialize like - 
     product = Product.new

You can if you so choose to have an initialize method which will do certain things with information that is passed in, namely make it available for the other methods to use. But I'll let you read up on that. Mostly, if you're developing using ruby on rails you probably wont need initialize.